# Python how do I split a string using a special character encoding error being returned

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am using selenium web driver to parse all text from a facebook profile, i.e. data mining. I need to parse by a special character but I'm getting a error when I try. I'm not sure why because I encode it before I use it but its still returning an error.

The character im trying to search is 'Â·'

If I split by this character each post will be broken up by row.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/userprofilelink")
inputEmail = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
inputEmail.send_keys("fbemail")
inputPass = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
inputPass.send_keys("fbpasswd")
inputPass.submit()
page_text = (driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text)
parse_data = soup.get_text().encode('utf-8').split('Name how it appears on post John Doe')
latest_message = parse_data[3]
```

This is where my error is occurring. I get :

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file  C:\Users\Administraor\workspace\NagioPlugins\selinium_test.py on line 19, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Code:

```
search_string = ('Â·').encode('utf-8')
latest_message = parse_data[3].split(search_string)
print latest_message
driver.close()

print latest_message
```

Comment: So why don't you actually read the link given to you? And why are you trying to encode a byte string? You'd have to **decode** to unicode.

Comment: Apart from the PEP link, you really should read up on Unicode first: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky, the  [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) and [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: Theres no link given when you split by name it will separates into about 7 index values 'this is all the post selenium loads, because its what is loaded by default when my browser visits my profile', then each row on the page is separated by this char Â·. thus, if i split each index entry with the special char Â· i will get them broken into individual rows. This will make it easier to parse things like time difference between post etc.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: I had to set the encoding of the script to utf 8.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/fbusername")
inputEmail = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
inputEmail.send_keys("fbemail")
inputPass = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
inputPass.send_keys("fbpasswd")
inputPass.submit()
page_text = (driver.page_source).encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_text)
parse_data = soup.get_text().encode('utf-8').split('·')
for i,v in enumerate(parse_data):
    print i,v

parse_data = soup.get_text().encode('utf-8').split('First Last')
for i,v in enumerate(parse_data):
    print i,v

latest_message = parse_data[4]
latest_message = parse_data[4].split('·')

driver.close()
print latest_message
```